# Python - How to change this design?

Tags: python

I have a list of methods of my user object, defined like so:

```
METHOD_ATTACK: {
    'func': User.handle_attack,
    ...
}
```

When handling these actions, I call like so:

```
user.handle_action(ACTION, *args)
```

The purpose of this is that there are various control parameters in the METHOD_* dictionary which abstract the control over the different functions, for instance what ones require the user to be in a specific state to allow the action to continue. handle_action checks those conditions before calling the action method to perform the action, if everything passes.

Now: I want to make a second type of User and override some of these methods in the derived class, so I want to call SpecialUser.handle_attack instead of User.handle_attack, if that exists.

One option is this:

```
METHOD_ATTACK: {
    'func': "handle_attack",
    ...
}

...

func = getattr(user, ACTION["func"])
```

This adds an extra getattr call to look up every action.

Another option is to duplicate all the METHOD_*'s for SpecialUser, but this feels redundant.

What design would be best suited to this change?

Comment: Why have you created your own object system?

Comment: I have lots of constraints on the actions and found it easier to summarize those constraints in a dictionary than to write them all out in every action method.

Comment: Ah, also, getattr is not that expensive, it happens all the time in python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One common idiom is to have these as methods in a class, with a prefix.

```
class User(object):
    def action_attack(self):
        ...

    def handle_action(self, name):
        method = getattr(self, 'action_' + name)
        method()

class SpecialUser(User):
    def action_attack(self):
        ...
```

By the way, the object oriented programming means that the objects know their state and act upon messages; by having the controls outside the objects you are really defeating this mechanism. Thus just do the checks for correct state within the User's methods. Even if the states are described in a dictionary, then check them within the object.